# VBA, Looping through Directory contains corrupt file, bypass?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, directory

I have a macro that goes through a large directory of files and performs a task. However the macro stops when it gets to a certain file that has 'unreadable content'. (excel files)

What can I add to my code to skip these files? What area of my code do I place it?

Tried adding this to my code after i declare my variables, doesn't do anything though.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Many thanks

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Posting part of my vba code, just a note: 'UserInput' is a function. If you need more posted to better understand let me know and i'll post.

```
'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary

Debug.Print fileNames(Key)
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key), CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
```

EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Going to upload full code. This is with the recommended changes.

```
Sub ladiesman()
'includes filling down

Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer
    Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range, z As Range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long

    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long

     ' Turn off screen updating and automatic calculation
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

     ' Create a new worksheet, if required
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Unique data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wksSummary Is Nothing Then
        Set wksSummary = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        wksSummary.Name = "Unique data"
    End If

     ' Set the initial output range, and assign column headers
    With wksSummary
        Set y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
        Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
        lngStartRow = y.Row
        .Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("File Name", "Sheet Name", "Node Name", "Scenario Name")
    End With

'get user input for files to search
Set fileNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
errCheck = UserInput.FileDialogDictionary(fileNames)
If errCheck Then
   Exit Sub
End If
'''
For Each Key In fileNames 'loop through the dictionary




On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error when loading " & fileNames(Key)
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb
End If



 ' Check each sheet in turn
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
             ' Only action the sheet if it's not the 'Unique data' sheet
            If .Name <> wksSummary.Name Then
                boolWritten = False

                 ' Find the Scenario column
                intColScenario = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColScenario = WorksheetFunction.Match("scenarioName", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColScenario > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column E
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColScenario)) > 1 Then
                         ' Find the next free column, in which the extract formula will be placed
                        intColNext = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

                         ' Assign formulas to the next free column to identify the scenario name to the left of the first _ character
                        .Cells(1, intColNext).Value = "Test"
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColScenario).End(xlUp).Row
                        Set myrg = .Range(.Cells(2, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext))
                        With myrg
                            .ClearContents
                            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(LEFT(RC" & intColScenario & ",FIND(INDEX({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},1,MATCH(1,--(ISNUMBER(FIND({""+"",""-"",""_"",""$"",""%""},RC" & _
                            intColScenario & "))),0)), RC" & intColScenario & ")-1), RC" & intColScenario & ")"
                            .Value = .Value
                        End With

                         ' Copy unique values from the formula column to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
                        r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Name
                        r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Parent.Name

                         ' Clear the interim results
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNext), .Cells(lr, intColNext)).ClearContents

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        r.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        boolWritten = True
                    End If
                End If

                 ' Find the Node column
                intColNode = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColNode = WorksheetFunction.Match("node", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColNode > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column A
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColNode)) > 1 Then
                        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColNode).End(xlUp).Row

                         ' Copy unique values from column A to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details (if not already written)
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColNode), .Cells(lr, intColNode)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , y, True
                        If Not boolWritten Then
                            y.Offset(0, -1).Value = ws.Name
                            y.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Parent.Name
                        End If

                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        y.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    End If
                End If

         ' Identify the next row, based on the most rows used in columns C & D
                lngLastNode = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
                lngLastScen = wksSummary.Cells(wksSummary.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
                lngNextRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(lngLastNode, lngLastScen) + 1
                If (lngNextRow - lngStartRow) > 1 Then



                     ' Fill down the workbook and sheet names
                    z.Resize(lngNextRow - lngStartRow, 2).FillDown
                    If (lngNextRow - lngLastNode) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Node value
                        wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastNode, 3), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 3)).FillDown
                    End If
                    If (lngNextRow - lngLastScen) > 1 Then
                         ' Fill down the last Scenario value
                        wksSummary.Range(wksSummary.Cells(lngLastScen, 4), wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow - 1, 4)).FillDown
                    End If
                End If



                Set y = wksSummary.Cells(lngNextRow, 3)
                Set r = y.Offset(0, 1)
                Set z = y.Offset(0, -2)
                lngStartRow = y.Row
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
Next 'End of the fileNames loop
Set fileNames = Nothing

 ' Autofit column widths of the report
wksSummary.Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.AutoFit

' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have some search code that loops through many Excel files as safely as I could make it (disabling macro autoexecution, disabling events, link updates etc, and ignoring errors), and it still sometimes stops in the middle of the loop for no reason. I failed to find a way to completely guard from this.

Comment: Hmm intriguing. What method do you use to ignore errors?

Comment: You only want to perform task on certain files yes? Is there a pattern to those files? If so, do a conditional loop. Alternatively, how many files are corrupt? Are they constant? Do a blacklist for them.

Comment: Please post the VBA code of your macro (or the relevant part). At which line does it stop? Is there an error message?

Comment: @findwindow, yes excel files, some of them are corrupt. Would like to skip them, possibly get the file name of the skipped files and put somewhere. Its not constant, there could be 100's of files.

Comment: @Andre451 "Method of 'Open' of Object 'workbooks' failed" is the error message. Stopping at line `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key), CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile)`   ... Im posting the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip the unreadable file, you should get rid of `CorruptLoad:=xlRepairFile` (apparently it doesn't work for your files anyways), and use `On Error Resume Next` directly before trying to open the file.

Like this:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wb = Nothing    ' or set a boolean error flag
End If
On Error GoTo 0    ' or your custom error handler

If wb Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error when loading " & fileNames(Key)
Else
    Debug.Print "Successfully loaded " & fileNames(Key)
    wb.Application.Visible = False 'make it not visible
    ' more working with wb
    ' all
    ' your
    ' code
    ' goes
    ' here :)
End If
```

**Edit**

**All** the code from

```
' Check each sheet in turn
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

(you should use `wb` here instead of `ActiveWorkbook`)

to

```
wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save
Set wb = Nothing 'release the object
```

belongs in the Else part directly after (or rather instead of) my placeholder comment

```
' more working with wb
```

All of this should only be done, if the workbook has been successfully loaded.

---

**Edit 2**

About `wb` vs `ActiveWorkbook`:
It improves the robustness of your code to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveSheet` etc. as much as possible, especially when working with multiple workbooks. Some later changes to your code may make a different workbook active at the time you use it, and suddenly your code will fail. (Probably not in this function here, but it's a general rule of thumb.)

`wb` was just assigned to the opened workbook

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileNames(Key))
```

so it's good practice to use the `wb` variable for everything you do with that workbook.

For the skipped files:
Instead of

```
Debug.Print "Error when loading " & fileNames(Key)
```

simply collect them in a string

```
strErrorFiles = strErrorFiles & vbCrLf & fileNames(Key)
```

and later `MsgBox` that string. But note that `MsgBox` has a limit to the number of text it will show, so if there may be lots of error files, better write them to a sheet.

Comment: Now I get an error on `wb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the workbook do not save` at the bottom of my code  . In the immediate window gives an error for that file name. Im going to post my full code if that will help.

Comment: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: @Ladiesman191: see edit. `wb.Close` cannot work if `wb` is Nothing, because it hasn't been loaded.

Comment: thanks Andre, I put everything from you mentioned between the Else part and worked perfect! I do not understand the comment you made to switch `wb` instead of `activeworkbook` and how this will affect the macro?

Comment: Also, andre, this may be new question, but is there a quick code I can use to take the file names skipped and populate it on a sheet or msgbox

Comment: Thanks Andre, how could I put them from the string into a new sheet , I already create a sheet in this code but I wouldnt mind creating a new one to put the file names of the skipped files.

Comment: there could be many files, so the msgbox  might not be the best idea